# Files.newInputStream creates slow InputStream

Tags: java

On my Windows 7 Files.newInputStream returns sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream. When I tested its performance vs FileInputStream I was surprised to know that FileInputStream is faster.

This test

```
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("test");
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    byte[] a = new byte[16 * 1024];
    for (int n; (n = in.read(a)) != -1;) {
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0);
```

reads 100mb file in 125 ms. If I replace the first line with

```
InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("test"));
```

I get 320ms.

If Files.newInputStream is slower what advantages it has over FileInputStream?

Comment: 100MB is nowhere near enough to exercise the system.  Anything running in background could have easily interfered with I/O.  Try it with about 100 times more data (10GB) and nothing running in the background to get meaningful numbers.

Comment: The overhead of those blocking file channel adapters is pretty bad. I guess using a FileChannel directly would be ok but that work around...(not saying that your benchmark is valid :)

Comment: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/fileinputstream-fileoutputstream-considered-harmful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you tested `new FileInputStream` second, you are probably just seeing the effect of cache priming by the operating system. It isn't plausible that Java is causing any significant difference to an I/O-bound process. Try it the other way around, and on a much larger dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Your `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputstreams` might introduce long GC pauses

Every time you create either a `FileInputStream` or a `FileOutputStream`, you are creating an object. Even if you close it correctly and promptly, it will be put into a special category that only gets cleaned up when the garbage collector does a full GC. Sadly, due to backwards compatibility constraints, this is not something that can be fixed in the JDK anytime soon as there could be some code out there where somebody has extended `FileInputStream / FileOutputStream` and is relying on those `finalize()` methods to ensure the call to `close()`.

The solution (at least if you are using Java 7 or newer) is not too hard
— just switch to `Files.newInputStream(...)` and `Files.newOutputStream(...)`

https://dzone.com/articles/fileinputstream-fileoutputstream-considered-harmful

Comment: This is reported by SpotBugs for the GC reason.

Comment: FileOutputStream/FileInputStream will not override finalize() in Java 11 anymore. So, in Java 11, you can again use FileOutputStream/FileInputStream (last comment on page you referenced). Also see comment of Kirk Pepperdine

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to be the buzzkill, but the javadoc doesn't state any advantages, nor does any documentation I could find

> Opens a file, returning an input stream to read from the file. **The
>   stream will not be buffered**, and is not required to support the mark
>   or reset methods. **The stream will be safe for access by multiple
>   concurrent threads.** Reading commences at the beginning of the file.
>   Whether the returned stream is asynchronously closeable and/or
>   interruptible is highly file system provider specific and therefore
>   not specified.

I think the method is just a utility method not necessarily meant to replace or improve on `FileInputStream`. Note that the concurrency point might explain some slow down.

Comment: API does not say FileInputStream is not thread safe. Note that FileInputStream uses a volatile field and a ThreadLocal internally

Answer (score -2):

The document said

"The stream will not be buffered"

It's because  Files.newInputStream(Paths) support non-blocking IO.

You can try in debug mode, you can open non blocking inputstream and in the same time modify the file, but if you use FileInputStream, you cannot do such things.

FileInputStream will require "write lock" of file, so it can buffer the content of file, increase the speed of reading.

But ChannelInputStream cannot. It must guaranteed that it is reading the "current" content of file.

Above is my experience, I didn't check every point in Java doc.

Comment: Java input streams do not support non-blocking I/O,; there is no non-blocking I/O to files in Java via any means; and even if there was, it wouldn't explain this speed difference. `FileInputStream` isn't buffered either, and doesn't require a write lock. You seem to be confusing locking with blocking modes, and both with buffering. They are three different things, and they don't affect each other. Your answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: There is no need to have a buffer (in the given benchmark) since the reads are 16k in size (which would not use the buffer anyway). Besides that there is no such thing as a write lock for a read.